# while loop could not break

Tags: python, exception, while-loop

there is `NameError: name 'user' is not defined`

**why while loop is not ending please help to find the problem**

*this program is for dice roll in pyhton*
I want to roll the dice with no exception but there are exception accured

````
rand_num=random.randint(1, 6)
game_is_on=True    
while True:
    try:
        user=int(input("What's your choice : "))
        continue
    except:
        print("Please Enter 1-6")

    if user == rand_num:
        print("\t congrats ! \n You guessed it right ")
    elif user != rand_num:
        print("Sorry! your guess is incorrect")
        
    replay=input("Do you want to play again (Yes/No)")
    if replay =='yes'.lower():
        game_is_on=True
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing this game")
        game_is_on=False```


hlep to find the problem please
````

Comment: `while game_is_on`? you are no changing the loop condition. You can also just use `break` instead of a variable.

Comment: The `continue` should be moved to the end of the except-block (which would be better defined as `except ValueError:`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your loop to exit:

- Your while loop will forever be true, but you switched a variable `game_is_on` that was meant to regulated the loop. Instead of the forever loop , `game_is_on` should be next to while,
- You need to remove `continue` statement as that line will just go to the next iteration as long as the condition is true,
- When asked about replaying, the lower part should be on the variable, instead of lowering the string itself.

Below is the code you need:

```
rand_num=random.randint(1, 6)
game_is_on=True
# while True:    
while game_is_on:
    try:
        user=int(input("What's your choice : "))
        # continue
    except:
        print("Please Enter 1-6")

    if user == rand_num:
        print("\t congrats ! \n You guessed it right ")
    elif user != rand_num:
        print("Sorry! your guess is incorrect")
        
    replay=input("Do you want to play again (Yes/No)")
    if replay.lower() =='yes':
        game_is_on=True
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing this game")
        game_is_on=False
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Now I have new error that is nameError 'user' not defined

Comment: Can you please share you stack trace? The code above works perfectly on my side.

Comment: @JulienNyambal As pointed out earlier, the `continue` needs to go in the except-block, otherwise `user` will be undefined on the first iteration if invalid input is entered. (Alternatively, the code below could be moved into an else-block). If you enter e.g. "x" you will see the error. Strictly speaking, the code should also raise an exception if a number outside the range 1-6 is entered, since we're rolling a standard die.

Comment: Thanks to all for helping me

Answer (score 0):

import random
rand_num=random.randint(1, 6)
game_is_on=True
while game_is_on:
try:
user=int(input("What's your choice : "))
except:
print("Please Enter 1-6")

```
if user == rand_num:
    print("\t congrats ! \n You guessed it right ")
elif user != rand_num:
    print("Sorry! your guess is incorrect")
    
replay=input("Do you want to play again (Yes/No)")
if replay =='yes'.lower():
    game_is_on=True
else:
    print("Thanks for playing this game")
    game_is_on=False
```

Note:
In while loop you have to write 'game_is_on' as for that variable it is telling whether true or false instead you have written True therefore your loop will never end as nothing is breaking the loop
corrected code is pasted above, hope this might help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator break to end while loop. lower() should be used with variable.

```
   if replay.lower() != 'yes':
    print("Thanks for playing this game")
    break
```